# Magento getting 500 error while saving CMS Page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

I am having a cms block which is used in footer and trying to add some content in it.

Example of content :-

> select from a wide range

But for some weird reason its not getting saved and showing 500 error.

**Note : If i put some other sentence it works fine.**

As far as i figured it out that magento is having trouble with sentences that are like sql queries.

Please help if some one faced similar issues earlier.

Comment: Wasn't able to duplicate this issue using 1.7. Do you have any firewall such as mod_security installed?

Comment: I think mod_security is a apache module. So i have raised a ticket to my hosting team to figure it out.

Comment: Also you may want to take a look at your server error logs since 500 is an internal server error

Comment: Getting same error, when i am just removing "from" text from cms page content then it is saving properly, otherwise it is giving 500 internal server error